# Test Class Code Coverage Issue with map

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Facing code coverage issue for this class. Can someone suggest test class

```java
public class IFB_InsertCaseSummaryObj implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    Map<String, Integer> m_ValueCountFirstMonth = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> m_ValueCountSecondMonthMonth = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> m_ValueCountThirdMonth = new Map<String, Integer>();
    DateTime varFirstDate ;
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,LOB_Field__c,IFB_Case_Type__c,IFB_Category__c,Status,Origin,
                                         IFB_SubCategory__c,CreatedDate from case where CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:3  order by createddate]
                                       );
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<case> scope){
        if(varFirstDate == null){
              varFirstDate = scope[0].createddate;
        }
        Integer firstMonth = varFirstDate.month();
        Integer intYear = varFirstDate.year();
        String strStartdate = intYear+'-'+firstMonth+'-01T00:00:00.000+0000';
        DateTime startDate =  Date.valueOf(strStartdate);
        DateTime secondMonthStartDate = startDate.addMonths(1);
        DateTime thirdMonthStartDate =  startDate.addMonths(2);
        System.debug(secondMonthStartDate+'   '+thirdMonthStartDate);
        for (case csObj: scope) {
        if(startDate <= csObj.createddate && csObj.createddate < secondMonthStartDate){
            String lobTypeCatSubCatFirstMonth = csObj.LOB_Field__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Case_Type__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Category__c+';'+csObj.IFB_SubCategory__c+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('MMMM')+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('YY')+';'+csObj.Origin+';'+csObj.Status;
            addToMap(m_ValueCountFirstMonth, lobTypeCatSubCatFirstMonth);
        }
        else if(secondMonthStartDate <= csObj.createddate && csObj.createddate < thirdMonthStartDate){
           String lobTypeCatSubCatSecondMonth = csObj.LOB_Field__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Case_Type__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Category__c+';'+csObj.IFB_SubCategory__c+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('MMMM')+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('YY')+';'+csObj.Origin+';'+csObj.Status;
            addToMap(m_ValueCountSecondMonthMonth, lobTypeCatSubCatSecondMonth);
        }
        else if (thirdMonthStartDate <= csObj.createddate){
             String lobTypeCatSubCatThirdMonth = csObj.LOB_Field__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Case_Type__c+';'+csObj.IFB_Category__c+';'+csObj.IFB_SubCategory__c+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('MMMM')+';'+csObj.CreatedDate.format('YY')+';'+csObj.Origin+';'+csObj.Status;
            addToMap(m_ValueCountThirdMonth, lobTypeCatSubCatThirdMonth);
        }
        }        
        
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
        
        List<IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c> lstCs= new List<IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c>();
        /* ------ START ---------------- Prepare first Month data */
        
        if(m_ValueCountFirstMonth.size()>0){
            for (String key : m_ValueCountFirstMonth.keySet()) {
                lstCs.add(createSummary(m_ValueCountFirstMonth, key, 'Third Last Month'));
            } 
        /* ------ END ---------------- Prepare first Month data */
        /* ------ START ---------------- Prepare second Month data */
        
        if(m_ValueCountSecondMonthMonth.size()>0){
            for (String key : m_ValueCountSecondMonthMonth.keySet()) {
                lstCs.add(createSummary(m_ValueCountSecondMonthMonth, key, 'Second Last Month'));
            }  
        }
        /* ------ END ---------------- Prepare second Month data */
        /* ------ START ---------------- Prepare third Month data */

        if(m_ValueCountThirdMonth.size()>0){
            for (String key : m_ValueCountThirdMonth.keySet()) {
                lstCs.add(createSummary(m_ValueCountThirdMonth, key, 'Last Month'));
            }            
        }
        /* ------ END ---------------- Prepare third Month data */  
            if(lstCs.size()>0){
                insert lstCs;
            }
            System.debug('Batch Run Successfully');
        }    
    }

    private static IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c createSummary(Map<String, Integer> m, String key, String month){
        IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c cS =  new IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c();
        List<String> lstKEY = key.split(';');
        cS.IFB_Subject__c = lstKEY[1]+' '+ lstKEY[2]+' '+ lstKEY[3];
        cS.IFB_LOB__c= lstKEY[0];
        cS.IFB_Case_Type__c=lstKEY[1];
        cS.IFB_Category__c=lstKEY[2];
        cS.IFB_Sub_Category__c=lstKEY[3];
        cS.IFB_Count__c = m.get(key);
        cS.IFB_Month__c = month;
        cS.IFB_Case_Created_Date__c = lstKEY[4]+' '+ lstKEY[5];
        cS.IFB_Case_Origin__c=lstKEY[6];
        cS.IFB_Status__c=lstKEY[7];
        Integer  number1 = m.get(key);
        System.debug(key+' = '+number1);
        return cS;
    }

    private static void addToMap(Map<String, Integer> m, String key){
        if(!m.containsKey(key)){
            m.put(key, 0); //initial count will be "0"
        }
        m.put(key, m.get(key)+1);
    }
}
```

```java
@isTest
public class IFB_InsertCaseSummaryObjTest {
    /*-------- String Constants-------------------------------------------*/
    private static final String strSYS_ADMIN = 'System Administrator';
    Private static final String strCategory = 'Deposits';
    Private static final String strSubCat = 'Account Upgrade';
    Private static final String strOpenStat = 'Draft';
    Private static final String strAssignToDep = 'Assigned To Department';
    Private static final String strKYCChnl = 'Video KYC';
    Private static final String strOrigin = 'AEM';
    private static final String strBUSINESS='Business';
    private static final String strTATA_FAMILY = 'Tata Family';
    private static final String strNANA_FAMILY = 'NANA Family';
    private static final String strABC = 'abc';
    private static final String strRURAL = 'Rural';
    private static final String strBANKING_COMPANY = 'Banking Company';
    private static final String strBKC_NAMAN = 'BKC - Naman Branch';
    private static final String strOwner = 'Video KYC BOC';
    private static final String strMAHARASHTRA = 'Maharashtra';
    private static final String strBRANCH_CODE = '40101';
    private static final String strMUMBAI = 'Mumbai';
    private static final String strDESCRIPTION = 'Branch Description';
    private static final String strWEST = 'West';
    private static final String STR_KycDate = '2020-04-02';
    private static final String STR_accNumber = '12312321';
    private static final String STR_CA_Status = null;
    private static final String STR_App_Id = '1232134';
   // private static final String strDepartment = '80353';
   // private static final Id ownerId = ''
    /*------------ Int Constanst--------------------------------------*/
    private static final Integer intONE = 1;
    private static final Integer intZERO = 0;
    /*------------Boolen Constants-------------------------------------*/
    private static final Boolean blnFALSE = false;
    private static final Boolean blnTRUE = true;
    
    @testSetup
    private static void dataSetup(){
        
        List<User> lstUser;
        Account objAcc;
        IFB_Branch__c objBranch;
        Id idAccountRecordType;
        Case objCase;
        List<Case> caseList;
        Id idRecordType;
        lstUser = IFB_TestFactory.insertUser(intONE, strSYS_ADMIN);
        System.runAs(lstUser[intZERO]){
            objBranch = IFB_TestFactory.createBranchRecord(strBKC_NAMAN, strMAHARASHTRA,strBRANCH_CODE, strMUMBAI, strDESCRIPTION, strWEST, blnTRUE);
            objAcc = IFB_TestFactory.CreateAccount(strTATA_FAMILY, strABC, strRURAL, strBANKING_COMPANY, objBranch.Id, blnTRUE);
            caseList = IFB_TestFactory.createVKYCPELogRecords(STR_accNumber, objAcc.IFB_UCIC__c, strKYCChnl, STR_KycDate, STR_CA_Status, STR_App_Id, strOpenStat, strCategory, strSubCat, intZERO);
        }
    }
        @isTest
        static void runBatchForCasesummary(){
            List<Case> newList = new List<Case>();
            List<User> lstUser = IFB_TestFactory.insertUser(intONE, strSYS_ADMIN);
            System.runAs(lstUser[intZERO]){
            List<Case> csList = [Select id,IFB_category__c,owner.name,ownerId,IFB_subcategory__c,status,IFB_SR_Pickup_Branch__c, IFB_Branch_Code__c, IFB_Case_Owner__c, isclosed,IFB_CA_Status__c, IFB_Department__c, lastmodifieddate,IFB_KYC_Channel__c from case];
            System.debug('Case list size'+csList.size());
                
             id idRecordType =  Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Request').getRecordTypeId();   
            Group queueList = [Select id, name, type from Group where name = 'Video KYC BOC' AND Type ='Queue' limit 1];
            IFB_Branch__c branchList = [SELECT id, Name, IFB_Branch_Code__c from IFB_Branch__c where Name = 'BKC - Naman Branch' limit 1];
   
                for(Case cs : csList){
                    cs.IFB_SR_Pickup_Branch__c = branchList.IFB_Branch_Code__c;
                    cs.OwnerId = queueList.id;
                    cs.Origin = 'AEM';
                    cs.RecordTypeId = idRecordType;
                    newList.add(cs);
                }
                Update newList;
                Test.startTest();
                IFB_InsertCaseSummaryObj Ic = new IFB_InsertCaseSummaryObj();
                Database.executeBatch(Ic, 10);
                Test.stopTest();
                
               
        }
         /* List<IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c> csd = [Select id, owner.name, IFB_Subject__c from IFB_Case_Summary_Data__c limit 1];
            if(csd.size() > 0) {
            System.assertEquals('Liabilities', csd[0].IFB_LOB__c);
            }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also add the test class that you have tried so far? It would also be helpful to share exact problem you are facing while writing the test class.

Comment: added test class

Comment: After a cursory look it seems that since you are querying case records, it might not have all the conditions met, the query might return cases created in the same month. Instead, it might be better to create new case records and set created date on them such that they meet the if criterias.